# Change default naming-behavior for operation_id

Tags: fastapi

If I generate a Java client based on the following endpoint:

```py
api_users = APIRouter(prefix='/api/users', tags=['users'])


class User(BaseModel):
    name: str


@api_users.get(
    path='',
    response_model=List[User],
)
async def get_users():
    return [User(name='test')]
```

The method name inside the `UserApi.java` file for it will be `getUsersApiUsersGet()` instead of `getUsers()`. I have to set the `operation_id` to something like `get_users` as in

```py
@api_users.get(
    path='',
    response_model=List[User],
    operation_id='get_users'
)
```

but this is tedious. Why isn't it just grabbing the method name itself, and uses this as default value instead?

So, is there a way I can change that behavior?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Are you trying to call python code from `java`?

Comment: @lsabi Already figured it out. But thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit weird that this is not standard behavior but we can achieve this by running this:

```py
def use_route_names_as_operation_ids(application: FastAPI) -> None:
    """
    Simplify operation IDs so that generated API clients have simpler function
    names.

    Should be called only after all routes have been added.
    """
    for route in application.routes:
        if isinstance(route, APIRoute):
            route: APIRoute = route
            route.operation_id = route.name


app = FastAPI()
controller.initialize(app)
use_route_names_as_operation_ids(app)  # Call after controller were initialized
```